# Cannot find module @angular/common/http/src/params after updating to angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

After updating from Angular 7 to the latest version (8), had some issues that I was able to fix but I couldn't find a solution for this.

```
Cannot find module '@angular/common/http/src/params'.
```

My code:

```
        const options: HttpParamsOptions = {
            fromObject: params,
            encoder: this.httpParamEncoder
        };
```

Comment: I wonder, Why do you use classes from the `src/**` directory? We are supposed to use only what's provided through the angular public API.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are importing `HttpParamsOptions` interface from `@angular/common/http/src/params`:

```
import { HttpParamsOptions } from '@angular/common/http/src/params';
```

This issue was also discussed on the Angular's Github repository:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23523,
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22013,
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20276

The problem is that the `HttpParamsOptions` interface is not exported by the public API, although it is used in `HttpParams` which is part of the public API:

```
export declare class HttpParams {
    constructor(options?: HttpParamsOptions);
    ...
}
```

The current workaround is to include the interface in your own code, by copying the interface from Angular source code, as found in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8a0e45826a4f140e9330d57594c338276a151401/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L76

```
/** Options used to construct an `HttpParams` instance. */
export interface HttpParamsOptions {
   /**
    * String representation of the HTTP params in URL-query-string format. Mutually exclusive with
    * `fromObject`.
    */
   fromString?: string;

   /** Object map of the HTTP params. Mutually exclusive with `fromString`. */
   fromObject?: {
      [param: string]: string | string[];
   };

   /** Encoding codec used to parse and serialize the params. */
   encoder?: HttpParameterCodec;
}
```

Then initialize http params as follows:

```
const httpParamsOptions: HttpParamsOptions = { fromObject: { aaa: '111', bbb: '222' } };
const httpParams = new HttpParams(httpParamsOptions);
```

StackBlitz demo with full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cizc36.